# loop to add present state with previous state

Tags: matlab, loops

I want to make a loop in order to add the current state with the previous state.

For example:

```
M=1000; 
for i=1:M A=i*(x(i));
```

This formula will be for `M=1` but when `M=2` the formula will be like this:

```
A=(i*(x(i))+((i-1)*(x(i-1)))
```

and when `M=3` the formula will be

```
A=(i*(x(i))+((i-1)*(x(i-1)))+((i-2)*(x(i-2))
```

and so on till reach the maximum length of `M` which is `1000`.

Comment: This is not clear. Please include a worked example of a small (say 4 elements or so) vector, add both the input and the output to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is quite vague but it sounds like you just want a cumulative sum of the i*x(i) series:

```
i = 1:M;
s = i.*x(i);

cumsum(s);
```

Comment: I think `sum(s)` is what he is asking for. But since his question is quite vaque i ain't sure. Maybe you should add it with explanation of what results in what. Anyway nice solution

Comment: Thanks Dear Dan for your answer. My question is that I want to to add the sum of the first round of the loop the the sum of the second round of the loop and add the sum of the first and second rounds to the third one and so on till the end of the loop.

Comment: @user3725170 Well that's exactly what this does. Unless you add a worked example, I can't tell what more you could need.

Comment: Much thanks Dan for your help I really appreciate your answer. For now I'm getting this error Attempted to access x(2); index out of bounds because numel(x)=1.

Comment: if you only have 1 element in `x` then what's the point of your question??

Comment: this is the code with the error how can I make the code run
>>  M=3;
x=2;
for i=1:M
s = i*x(i);
cumsum(s);
end
Attempted to access x(2); index out of bounds because numel(x)=1.

Comment: @Rock `numel(x)` must be `M` or larger, otherwise the whole process makes no sense! If `x` is a scalar, then how can `x(i-1)` ever be defined?

Comment: Much thanks  Mr. Dan I really appreciate your help and I wish u a good day.